# Reading structures from a binary file

Tags: c++, file

I'm having troubles with loading data from a file. I've put a cout<<"entered the while loop" when reading and it keeps repeating until crashing, not showing any data of the file.

This is the part of the code that I find relevant to this question, if needed I'll provide more informations:

```
    struct Book
{
    char name[50];
    int bookID;
};

struct Writter
{
    char name[30];
    int writterID,
        bookAmount;
    struct Book book[20];
};

struct Publisher
{
    char name[20];
    int publisherID,
        qtAutor;
    Writter writter[30];
};

Publisher publisher[20];

    void savingData(){
                fflush(stdin);
                if((arquivo = fopen("contact.dat","wb+")) !=NULL){
                        cout<<"It enters the write part"<<endl;//just checking if it enters the write part
                        fwrite(&publisher,sizeof(publisher),1,arquivo);
                        fclose(arquivo);
                }

                else{
                    cout<<"Error: file cannot be opened";
                }
}//savingData

void loadingData(){
            fflush(stdin);

            if((arquivo = fopen("contact.dat","rb+")) !=NULL){
                while(!feof(arquivo)){
                    fread(&publisher,sizeof(publisher),1,arquivo);
                    if(!feof(arquivo)){
                    cout<<"Entered the while loop";
                    }//if

                }//while
fclose(arquivo);
            }//if

            else{
                cout<<"Error: file cannot be opened";
                }

}
```

I hope I didn't forget to translate anything.

EDIT: I did what Sam Varshavchik and took the fclose out. It only appears 1 time that it entered, but the information on the file is still not loaded.
On the file I have 1 publisher, 1 Writter and 2 books. I only write the names on the structs, everything else is added by increment.
[This is a print of the file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83pjZ.png)

Comment: It might help to put the line of code where it is crashing.  It doesn't need to loop actually.  You write an array of 20 elements and read an array of 20 elements.  It may be crashing because the 2nd loop is trying to read past the end of the file.

Comment: It keeps on repeating "Entered the while loop" until crashing.

Comment: How does it crash?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please review the elements of giving good examples of problems on the Internet, e.g. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Does your question require three struct definitions, or can you demonstrate the part that is your problem equally well with just one?  Does that one struct need three fields, or can one do just as well to show your problem?  You also need to supply all the parts of the problem--if it's dependent on a file, you need that too.  Note the "edit" button for improving the question.

Comment: A couple of notes: 1 - `fclose(...)` shouldn't be called until the `while` loop has terminated. 2 - Try passing `"rb"` to `fopen(...)` rather than `"rb+"`.  It may be safe, but the `+` additionally opens the file for writing.

Comment: Already did that, I just edited the post with more information

Answer (score 1):

```
fclose(arquivo);
```

On the first iteration of your `while` loop, this `FILE` will be closed. Once it's closed, the `FILE` is no longer valid. But the very next thing that will happen is:

```
while(!feof(arquivo)){
```

... it will try to check the `FILE` status again, to check if another iteration of the loop should happen. But this `FILE` is no longer valid; hence this is undefined behavior.

Your bug is that your code continues to use the `FILE`, after it is closed. Once you call `fclose`, it's game over. You can't touch the `FILE` object, or refer to it, in any way. It is gone. It ceased to exist. It is no more. It joined the choir-invisible. It's an ex-`FILE`.

Comment: I changed that and added a bit more to original post